# Не могу подключиться к mailcow почте через Thunderbird

Tags: linux, nginx, email

Есть корпоративная почти yandex и она привязана к домену. Пытаюсь поднять свой mailcow сервер для этого же домена, чтобы перенести старую корпоративную почту на свою.

Имею следующую сеть. Есть роутер и он пробрасывает 80 и 443 порты на ubuntu-server. На этом сервере работает и mailcow и nginx proxy manager. Оба работают через docker. NPM перенаправляет с https://mail.***.ru на https://localhost:4430(mailcow). Сертификат сгенерировал также через NPM. Админка и SOGo открываются по https://mail.***.ru. Все прекрасно работает. Письма уходят и приходят. Кач-во письма 10/10 по mail-tester.

Пытаюсь подключиться к аккаунту почты через сторонний клиент - тот же Thunderbird, но он по дефолту подхватывает imap и smtp от yandex для imap. При попытке аутентификации я получаю конечно ошибку, т.к я думаю он обращается к imap/smtp yandex, а там нет моего аккаунта, который есть на моем сервере. Я прав?

Могу ли я иметь несколько imap, smtp, pop для одного домена? Т.е, старые от яндекса и новые на своем сервере. Если да, то мне надо их также пробросить через NPM или я что-то делаю не так?